# Identify a piece in the air intake assembly

Tags: honda, civic, part-identification

I need to replace the part shown in the picture bellow (i'm not affiliated in any way with ahparts.com, i'm just borrowing their picture) in my car; However, I don't know the name of it. Can somebody tell me the name of this part? The vehicle's make and model is Honda Civic 2004.

[image: Part to identify]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the air intake resonator housing. Looks like the image is a still from a [YouTube video](http://youtu.be/hZKqUao6re8)